# Android studio pass token to javascript file

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

Currently I am working on **android studio** project where I need to call webservice API to generate token and use this token in `javascript sdk`. In my code, I can generate token but I am not sure how to use the token in javascript sdk.

This is the code where I request webservice API call and get token from API response.

```
    private void requestCreateCheckout() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response>() {
        @Override
        protected Response doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                Request request = new Request(Request.Method.POST, Config.getEnvironment()
                        == Config.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION ?
                        Config.API_PIPWAVE_PRODUCTION :
                        Config.API_PIPWAVE_SANDBOX);

                byte[] body = JSONUtils.toJSON(mInitiatePayment).toString().getBytes();
                request.setBody(body);

                String key = mClientKey + ":";
                String authorization = Base64.encodeToString(key.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("x-api-key", mInitiatePayment.getApi_key());
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
                headers.put("Content-Length", Integer.toString(body.length));
                request.setHeaders(headers);



                AndroidClient androidClient = new AndroidClient();
                return androidClient.call(request);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return new Response(-1, "");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
            if(response.getCode() == 200){
                try {
                    JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject(response.getResponse());

                    mSessionRedirectUrl =responseBody.getString("redirect_url");
                    mSessionToken = responseBody.getString("token");
                    mSessionStatus = responseBody.getString("status");
                    mSessionMessage = responseBody.getString("message");


                    String[] redirectUrlParts = mSessionRedirectUrl.split("\\?");
                    mSessionCheckoutId = redirectUrlParts[redirectUrlParts.length - 1];
                    if(Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase().contains("samsung")){
                        mSessionRedirectUrl += "&cssfix=true";
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    finishFailure(e.getMessage());
                }
            }else{
                finishFailure(response.getResponse());
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

This is the javascript code that I need to execute for using js sdk. The token should be from API response and not hardcoded.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var pwconfig = {"api_key":"zavIvQKJzY8m5fpeZogpm9pJOxQptp3e9NnRIZor","token":"ONyyQjvLv64iUg4B9p4jPbUJhIC9LCUE"};
    (function (_, p, w, s, d, k) {
        var a = _.createElement("script");
        a.setAttribute("data-main", w + s);    
        a.setAttribute('src', w + d);
        a.setAttribute('id', k);

        setTimeout(function() {
        var reqPwInit = (typeof reqPipwave != 'undefined');
            if (reqPwInit) {
                reqPipwave.require(['pw'], function(pw) {
                    pw.setOpt(pwconfig);
                    pw.startLoad();
                });
            } else {
                _.getElementById(k).parentNode.replaceChild(a, _.getElementById(k));
            }
        }, 800);

        })(document, 'script', "//staging-checkout.pipwave.com/sdk/", "pw.sdk.min.js", "lib/require.js", "pwscript");
    </script>
```

How can I parse token value from API response to the javascript file programmatically ? Then, execute that file.

---

**EDITS** 
As suggested to using rhino, here what I have done.

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
            if(response.getCode() == 200){
                try {
                    JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject(response.getResponse());

                    mSessionRedirectUrl =responseBody.getString("redirect_url");
                    mSessionToken = responseBody.getString("token");

                    String[] redirectUrlParts = mSessionRedirectUrl.split("\\?");
                    mSessionCheckoutId = redirectUrlParts[redirectUrlParts.length - 1];
                    if(Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase().contains("samsung")){
                        mSessionRedirectUrl += "&cssfix=true";
                    }

                    Object[] functionParams = new Object[]{response};

                    String js_script = "var pwconfig = {'api_key':"+ API_STAGING_KEY +", 'token':"+mSessionToken+"};" +
                            "function (_,p,w,s,d,k){" +
                            "var a = _.createElement('script');" +
                            "a.setAttribute('data-main', w + s);" +
                            "a.setAttribute('src', w + d);" +
                            "a.setAttribute('id', k);" +
                            "setTimeout(function(){" +
                            "var reqPwInit = (typeof reqPipwave != 'undefined');" +
                            "if(reqPwInit){" +
                            "reqPipwave.require(['pw'], function(pw){" +
                            "pw.setOpt(pwconfig);" +
                            "pw.startLoad();" +
                            "});" +
                            "}else{" +
                            "_.getElementById(k).parentNode.replaceChild(a, _.getElementById(k));" +
                            "}" +
                            "}, 800);" +
                            "})(document, 'script', '//staging-checkout.pipwave.com/sdk/','pw.sdk.min.js','lib/require.js', 'pwscript');";


                    Context rhino = Context.enter();
                    rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);

                    Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
                    rhino.evaluateString(scope, js_script, "JavaScript", 1, null);
                    Function function = (Function)scope.get("_,p,w,s,d,k", scope);

                    checkout = (String)function.call(rhino,scope,scope,functionParams);
                    loadUrl(checkout);

                } catch (JSONException | RhinoException e) {
                    finishFailure(e.getMessage());
                }finally {
                    Context.exit();
                }
            }else{
                finishFailure(response.getResponse());
            }
        }
```

I am using sample implementation of Rhino from this link https://github.com/brionmario/rhino-library-android. But still i cannot solve my issues. Or the code is wrong?

Comment: Look into Rhino.  You can run Javascript in an Android app with parameters.  https://www.google.com/search?q=rhino+android+javascript

Comment: nasch, as you suggested. I try to use rhino but it still cannot solve my issues.

Comment: What happens with the Rhino call?  And is this javascript running in a web page?  Because if so then I think Rhino is not the answer after all.

Comment: The error from toast message give me **syntax error (JavaScript#1)**. The result should be display in webview.

Comment: Then I think I steered you wrong, you don't want to use Rhino for this.  Not sure what the solution is, I have never used javascript in a web view in this manner.

Comment: thank you for your response. btw do you ever found android studio app that using custom javascript sdk?

Comment: No I don't think so.